# Why does coldfusion web page run before application.cfm is processed?

Tags: web-applications, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 11 on Windows2008 R2. From what I understand, if there is an application.cfm page in the root folder, that any .cfm page below the root will process this page first and then process the regular .cfm page. I noticed that it processes my regular page FIRST and then calls the application.cfm page.

In my case I have a web page that updates a database, but in my application.cfm page, I check a session variable to see if the user is logged in. If they are not logged in, then I redirect them to a log in page, let them log in, set the session variable and then redirect them back to process the page. But I noticed, that when I run the page, the database gets updated and THEN the user gets redirected to log in, then the database gets updated again.

Am I not using the application.cfm page correctly? I thought it was supposed to be used to check log ins and things like that. How do I ensure that it runs first?

Btw, it is the only application.cfm page in the entire web site and I do not have any application.cfc files.

Thanks.

Comment: application.cfm/cfc always runs first, however the events within it happen at different times during the page lifecycle. onSessionStart should definitely be running before onRequest *if it is a new session*.

Comment: The Application.cfm is supposed to execute the code you put there.  As others have stated, it does run first.  Troubleshooting this particular problem is similar to troubleshooting many other problems.  Look at what is happening.  cfdump and cfabort are your freinds.

Answer (score 5):

Application.cfm will run with every single request.  If you have some database hit inside of Application.cfm then you will hit that code with each page unless the redirect happens first.  Without seeing your exact code, your probably doing some variation on this flow:

> 1. User requests page.cfm
> 2. CF reads application.cfm before executing page.cfm and a) hits the database for some action inside of application.cfm and then b)
>      redirects you to login.cfm
> 3. CF reads application.cfm a second time (this time for login.cfm) and a) hits the database for some action inside application.cfm and
>      then b) lets you hit the login.cfm template.
> 4. CF reads application.cfm for a third time (this time for your login action page).  You set your session variables and bypass the
>      database (?)

This is all speculation. Post your code if this doesn't lead you to some resolution.

Comment: Note that application.cfc will give you a much clearer flow of events and is well worth switching to.